# What happens to First Republic Bank (FRC) Short Puts on acquisition by JP Morgan?

Tags: shorting-securities, put-options

I own 5 Short Puts with strike price @ 11.00 with expiry being 19th May 2023. Since trading is halted, I may not be able to execute or close the position. What will happen to this position once JP Morgan acquires it?

Comment: "I own 5 Short Puts " meaning you sold 5 puts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on the terms of the "acquisition" and whether or not the stock has any value at that time. Worst case for you is that the FRC stock is worthless and you will have to pay the put holder $11 per share.  Best case is that the stock has an acquisition value of more than $11 and you have to pay nothing (the options are worthless).

Considering it's trading at about $3.50 now, the current scenario is that you will lose around $7.50 per share (assuming that's close to the acquisition price).

Comment: If we look at WAMU and SVB as precedents, I suspect the current shareholders are going to be wiped out. In the Wamu press release the FDIC explicitly noted that "Claims by equity, subordinated and senior debt holders
were not acquired", but in the FRC press release they didn't, so maybe there's some hope left for the OP...

Comment: Best case is they bought the puts and cash out for max profit. I'm pretty confident there are no terms to consider, shareholders get wiped out.

Comment: Current news is that the shares are worthless. This happened after trading was halted, so the $3.50 does not reflect the latest share price - as I understand it.